# TextMeshPro reinstalled but not showing under ''Window'' menu

Tags: unity-game-engine, textmeshpro

I had to remove and reinstall TextMeshPro [image: Reinstalled TextMeshPro] and when I went under window to import TMP Essential Resources it wasn't there [image: not there].

How do i fix this?

[image: Console]

Here's the QuestionSo
[QuestionSO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIV1J.png)

Comment: Did you try relogging into unity

Comment: If you mean close and reopen the project then yes

Comment: No. I meant re logging into unity. As you have to login to have a license/token for the app and for it to get to the asset store

Answer (score 0):

You should sing in with your Unity ID again. Did you have any issues before you updated TMPRO? Is this your project, were you previously signed in with Unity ID?